# Cordova jQuery Mobile app, image not showing on device but can show on Chrome

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using `Cordova` and `jQuery Mobile` to build an mobile app. I test my app on browser simulator, it works well and shows all pictures.

However, when testing on an Android phone (HTC), the background image is there, but logo image cannot be found (there is a "image not found" image ).

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Can you extract your APK to see if the image is in there? Sounds like in the packaging process that image is not included.

Comment: @RegencySoftware after I put image into css file, it works. btw, how to extract APK?

Comment: You can use 7ZIP or WinZip to unzip it.  Maybe the easiest way rename it from .APK to .ZIP then extract the files.

Answer (score 0):

I put the image source into css file (as a background image of div), then it works.